# True way return view in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to load view correctly? i read in some tutorial, they do

```
return view::make('viewName');
```

first i create route in route.php that looked like this

```
Route::get('book/{judul}','BookController@viewJudul');
```

and then in my controller, i add this code :

```
    public function viewJudul($judul){
    $data = array(
            'judul'=>$judul
        );
    return View::make('book',$data);
}
```

but it give me error when i execute it, but i look into some example. The code is like this one :

```
    public function viewJudul($judul){
    $data = array(
            'judul'=>$judul
        );
    return View('book',$data);
}
```

and it work fine, can anyone tell me what is View::make? or it's for old laravel version to define view?

Comment: View::make syntax was used in laravel 4.* versions and laravel 5 has view only.

Comment: check this link:- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View::make` was for the older version of laravel, probably `laravel 4.2.*` i guess. For the question what you will want to use to render views in your code, I `suggest` you to do what `docs` suggest you and its important to follow the same convention throughout your code. In that case,

```
return view('book',$data);
```

this will be a better option.

Comment: yea it's older version, so i will use just like what you just suggest @sid thanks

Answer (score 1):

`view()` is a helper function for `View::make()` and `Response::view()`

You can use any of these..

```
return View::make();

return view();

return Response::view();

return response()->view();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('book')->with("data",$data);
```